# How to interpret output of get.edgelist() in igraph

Tags: r

I would like to know how to interpret the output of the `get.edgelist()` command in `igraph` in R.

for example I generate a random graph:

```
a=erdos.renyi.game(100,0.5, directed=TRUE)
a=get.edgelist(a)
```

This gives me two columns and I would think that the first one represents nodes and the second the corresponding connections.

But this doesn't seem to be the case because some numbers are only represented in the second column but not the first. How can this be?

Comment: but if then I would expect that if I generate a directed graph then all connection of node 97 should be in the first column but it has fewer than the other nodes.

Comment: I think you might be mixing up directed and undirected? In a directed graph, an edge goes *from* one node *to* the other node, in an undirected graph the direction doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a small example, probably it becomes obvious?

```
set.seed(45)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.5, directed = TRUE)
> get.adjacency(g)
10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 [1,] . 1 . 1 . . 1 1 1 1
 [2,] . . . 1 . 1 1 1 1 .
 [3,] 1 1 . 1 . 1 . . 1 .
 [4,] 1 1 . . . . 1 1 1 1
 [5,] . 1 . . . . 1 . . 1
 [6,] . 1 1 1 1 . 1 . . .
 [7,] 1 . 1 . . 1 . . 1 .
 [8,] . 1 1 1 . 1 . . 1 .
 [9,] 1 . 1 1 . 1 . . . 1
[10,] 1 . 1 . 1 1 . . 1 .

edges <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(g))
edges <- edges[order(edges$V1, edges$V2), ]
> head(edges, 11)
   V1 V2
7   1  2
18  1  4
34  1  7
39  1  8
42  1  9
1   1 10
19  2  4
28  2  6
35  2  7
40  2  8
43  2  9
```

You can see from the adjacency matrix that there are edges from `row 1` to `2,4,7,8,9,10`, which is also reflected in the output from `get.edgelist`. It gives you exactly what's in the adjacency matrix.

```
> table(edges$V1)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
# 6  5  5  6  3  5  4  5  5  5
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. My problem is that if you look at the remaining numbers in the edgelist above then you find that number 10 only has 5 contacts in column 2 whereas the others have 6. this is what I don't understand

Comment: yes. so there is no way to ensure that each node will ALWAYS have 5 but is there a way to ensure that each has AT LEAST 5?

Comment: yes, well the problem is that I would like to look at different probabilities of re-wiring but have for each case above 5 contacts for each agent. I guess I can only achieve that if I increase n. thanks for your help